# Raw XML Post using AFHTTPSessionManager

Tags: objective-c, cordova, afnetworking, afhttpsessionmanager

how can I send raw XML posts to a SOAP interface using `AFHTTPSessionManager`? The following code is a fork from https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP/blob/master/src/ios/CordovaHttpPlugin.m#L69:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.securityPolicy = securityPolicy;
NSString *url = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
NSDictionary *parameters = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:1];
NSDictionary *headers = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:2];
[self setRequestHeaders: headers forManager: manager];

CordovaHttpPlugin* __weak weakSelf = self;
manager.responseSerializer = [TextResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager POST:url parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [self setResults: dictionary withTask: task];
    [dictionary setObject:responseObject forKey:@"data"];
    CDVPluginResult *pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsDictionary:dictionary];
    [weakSelf.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, NSError *error) {
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [self setResults: dictionary withTask: task];
    NSString* errResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:(NSData *)error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [dictionary setObject:errResponse forKey:@"error"];
    CDVPluginResult *pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsDictionary:dictionary];
    [weakSelf.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}];
```

This posts `multipart/form-data` to the given (soap) url. Is it possible to alter the request so that it will send `text/xml` with a raw body?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the following solution to my problem:

NSString *url = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
    NSData *body = [[command.arguments objectAtIndex:2] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *headers = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:3];

```
CordovaHttpPlugin* __weak weakSelf = self;
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:url parameters:nil error:nil];
[req setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[req setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[req setHTTPBody:body];

manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

// Append headers
for (NSString* key in headers) {
    NSString *value = [headers objectForKey:key];
    [req setValue:value forHTTPHeaderField:key];
}

[[manager dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    NSDictionary *responseHeaders = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields];
    long status = (long) [(NSHTTPURLResponse *) response statusCode];
    NSLog(@"Status: %ld", status);

    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [dictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:status] forKey:@"status"];
    [dictionary setObject:responseHeaders forKey:@"headers"];

    if (!error) {
        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"POST SUCCESS: %@", responseString);
        //[self setResults: dictionary withTask: task];

        [dictionary setObject:responseString forKey:@"data"];

        CDVPluginResult *pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsDictionary:dictionary];
        [weakSelf.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
    } else {
        //[self setResults: dictionary withTask: task];
        NSString* errResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:(NSData *)error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        [dictionary setObject:errResponse forKey:@"error"];

        CDVPluginResult *pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsDictionary:dictionary];
        [weakSelf.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
    }
}] resume];
```